# Blocking Queue poll method retuns null during multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, blockingqueue

We have implemented multithreading in our application using blockingqueue, executor framework and future.

When ever user asks for some data, we submit a task to the executor framework which connects to database, queries data and streams the data back.

We have a method, Which reads this data and writes to servletoutputstrean.

```
public long writeData(ServletOutputStream sos, BlockingQueue < T > blockingQueue, Future < Boolean > future) {

    try (final JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sos, UTF_8))) {

        int counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            Optional.ofNullable(blockingqueue.poll()).ifPresent(entityobj - > {
                gson.toJson(entityobj, entityobj.getclass(), writer);
                Counter++;
            });



            if (blockingqueue.isEmpty() && future.isDone() && future.get()) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    Log.error("data not read properly");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

When blockingqueue.poll() is being executed, there are times data is still not loaded by the repositorythread.  By the time the next if block comes, blocking queue is empty and future is completed so control gets out of while loop.

No response is written to stream. Anyway to handle this weird behavior
This doesn't happen when there are lot of records.

Comment: Please can you format your code and fix typos (e.g. `While`). It's hard to tell what it's doing, but looks distinctly odd. What is `future`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: You've got a race between `blockingqueue.poll()` returning null, and checking if the queue is empty.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes. there is a race between poll() and isempty() method. I tried, poll(timeout,timeunits) . This is creating another issue, by always waiting till it timeout for all the calls.

Comment: Where is the `Future` object coming from, and what does it contain if done?

Comment: Don't use `poll()` in a busy loop.  When there is no data, that tries to waste a whole CPU doing nothing at all, heating up your room or draining you battery, and stealing time from other threads like your "repository thread".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When blockingqueue.poll() is being executed, there are times data is still not loaded by the repositorythread. By the time the next if block comes, blocking queue is empty and future is completed so control gets out of while loop.

You have a race condition in your code which is complicating matters:

```
if (blockingqueue.isEmpty() && /* race here */ future.isDone() && future.get()) {
```

There is a possibility that the `blockingqueue.isEmpty()` returns true and then the job finishes before the `future.isDone()` call happens causing the code to quit prematurely with an element left in the queue.

An "end of stream" object that @Willis mentioned is a good option but a simple solution would be to refactor your code like:

```
boolean futureDone = future.isDone();
entity = blockingqueue.poll();
if (entity == null) {
   if (futureDone) {
      break;
   }
} else {
   // process entity
}
```

This ensures that you always check to see if the future is done *before* getting the last item from the blocking-queue which removes the race.  You might have to do a poll one more time but that fine.

Btw, if this code is really spinning, you should put some sort of timeout in poll to slow it down and not eat a CPU:

```
entity = blockingqueue.poll(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: tried this solution and it was pretty easy to implement as well

Answer (score 3):

I think that `writeData` is operating as a worker that waits for data to show up on the `BlockingQueue` and then "writes" it. Your problem is that sometimes it takes the thread that is inserting data into the `BlockingQueue` (code not shown here) a while to load the data from wherever it comes from, causing your `writeData` worker to think that it's done and exit.

The best solution is to write some "end of stream" object to the `BlockingQueue` to signal when there is no more data, rather than relying on the absence of data in the queue.

You don't know exactly what type of object is in a `BlockingQueue<T>` (it's just `T`), so there are a couple of ways to do this.

The first way is to have whatever code provides `T` also provide an instance of `T` that will represent the end of the stream that you can check with either `equals` or even the equality operator `==`. Whether or not this is practical will depend on what kinds of `T` you have.

The other option is to make it a `BlockingQueue<Optional<T>>` and have the other thread write `Optional.empty()` to the queue when there is no more data.

In either case you can then call `poll()` with a timeout value and take appropriate action if it times out (failing, checking if the thread that is inserting into the queue is still alive, etc.).

Comment: Notifying end of stream as well worked for me as second approach. thanks a lot